# Replace CSS ruleset which have empty declaration block

Tags: c#, css, regex

I'm looking for a way to remove empty CSS declaration-blocks from a CSS string.
Because I use a lot of Sass-mixins, the generated CSS contains a lot of CSS rules without declarations. To shave off some file size of the stylesheet that is being sent to the browser I want to remove those rulesets.

Here's an example of my CSS:

```
.my-selector {
   color: red;
}
.my-selector .sub-selector {}
.my-selector .with-whitespace {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this with a Regex. Below is my implementation in C#.

```
css = Regex.Replace(css, @"[^\};\{]+\{\s*\}", "");
```

It is working for empty media-queries also.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\};\{\n]+\{\s*\}
```

Try this.This will work better.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/7

Yours will fail in this case.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/8

Comment: When a rule is splitted in multiple lines, it is still a valid rule right? So why is yours better? It only replaces have of the rule.

Comment: @WillemdeWit if the file has some other stuff up and below which is not a part of rules then?